# Windows 10 - Internet Explorer Development

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I am upgrading my development machine to Windows 10, however, our shipping software is browser based. The shipping software interacts with scales, printers...etc via ActiveX. Obviously, Windows 10 has Edge instead of IE and does away with ActiveX I believe, but I will still need to test new features and such. Is there a way to fully emulate IE 9 and 10 in Windows 10? I could do a virtual machine but I am not sure how this would interact with attached printers, dimensioners and scales. So I'm wondering if there are any cleaner methods out there.
As an aside, their software (not programmed by me) runs in quirks mode (I know...), so the emulation would need to be pretty spot on. Worst case, I can dual boot, but that won't be fun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 10 does still ship with Internet Explorer.  There are a couple ways to access it.

1. Open any webpage in Edge and click the ellipses and choose "Open with Internet Explorer".
2. From file explorer, browse to "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplorer.exe"

Comment: Ah, that's excellent news. My setup isn't complete yet so I wasn't sure. At least MS included that for the transitional phase.

Comment: Yes, yes it is.  Edge is coming along nicely, but it is lacking some essential features still (like plugin support!).  I'll be putting IE on the taskbar for some of my relatives.  Once you verify the steps, please mark as accepted answer :)

Comment: After finally getting the RAM for my new machine, I can confirm what you said. It looks like it's IE 11 and has access for IE 5, 7, 8, 9, 10 document modes as well.